# There is same way to import multiple custom font using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to show some custom fonts that I use as icon ... but its a big list and I don't want to import one by one because its gonna take a long time and will be hard to maintaining. I'm getting the font list from a API there is same way to import the fonts list using javascript?

The only way I could do so far was using `@font-face` with pure css, but with that I will need to import one by one.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Animal-1';
    src:  url('http://ggt-des.ibge.gov.br/styles/fontes/Animal-1.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
};
```

Font List:

```
{"Animais-1.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/Animais-1.ttf",
"Animais-2.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/Animais-2.ttf",
"Animais.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/Animais.ttf",
"CPRM_Fontes.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/CPRM_Fontes.ttf",
"ESRI-Electric.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/ESRI-AMFM-Electric.ttf",
"ESRI-AMFM-Gas.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/ESRI-AMFM-Gas.ttf"}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the svg version of the font?

Comment: @joseluismurillorios Just the ttf format...

Comment: Please don't use `ttf` in webcontext. Convert them to `woff2`, and use that instead. For one, `ttf` is a system font format, and so your font may get rejected over things that for webfonts is irrelevant, but secondly `woff2` (and `woff`, but there is barely any reason to use the v1 woff format in 2019) is a lossless compressed format, meaning you site will load much faster for your users.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Do you know any software or services that do the conversion to indicate?

Comment: The default choice is https://github.com/google/woff2 (and depending on your OS, that might be a simple as `apt-get install woff2` or `brew install woff2` or the like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can append `style` element to the `head` using javascript. Like below code snippet.

**DEMO**

```js
let head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
  style = document.createElement('style'),
  fonts = {
    "Animais-1.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/Animais-1.ttf",
    "Animais-2.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/Animais-2.ttf",
    "Animais.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/Animais.ttf",
    "CPRM_Fontes.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/CPRM_Fontes.ttf",
    "ESRI-Electric.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/ESRI-AMFM-Electric.ttf",
    "ESRI-AMFM-Gas.ttf": "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/ESRI-AMFM-Gas.ttf"
  };

head.appendChild(style);

style.type = 'text/css';

let css = Object.entries(fonts).map(v => `@font-face {
    font-family: "${v[0].split('.')[0]}";
    src:  url(${v[1]});
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}`).join('');

if (style.styleSheet) {
  // This is required for IE8 and below.
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
```

```css
.one {
  font-family: "Animais-1";
}

.two {
  font-family: "Animais-2";
}

.three {
  font-family: "Animais";
}

.four {
  font-family: "CPRM_Fontes";
}

.five {
  font-family: "ESRI-Electric";
}

.six {
  font-family: "ESRI-AMFM-Gas";
}
```

```html
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
<div class="four">4</div>
<div class="five">5</div>
<div class="six">6</div>
```

---

Other way you could use [`mixin`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) using SASS but for this you need to create `.scss` file instead of `.css`.

1. In `.scss` file you need to create `@mixin`, it's like a function.
2. And after you need to use that `mixin` using `@include` with passing parameters, it's like calling a function.

**MIXIN example**

```css
@mixin font-face($name, $path, $weight: null, $style: null){
    @font-face {
        font-family: quote($name);
        font-style: $style;
        font-weight: $weight;
        src: $path;
    }
}
@include font-face("Animais-2", "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/Animais-1.ttf", 'normal', 'normal');
@include font-face("Animais-2", "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/Animais-2.ttf", 'normal', 'normal');
@include font-face("Animais", "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/Animais.ttf", 'normal', normal);
@include font-face("CPRM_Fontes", "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/CPRM_Fontes.ttf", 'normal', 'normal');
@include font-face("ESRI-Electric", "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/ESRI-Electric.ttf", 'normal', 'normal');
@include font-face("ESRI-AMFM-Gas", "http://ggt-des.br/styles/fontes/ESRI-AMFM-Gas.ttf", 'normal', 'normal');
```